# Are we allowed to interchange product and inverse limits?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem, profinite-groups

Currently, I am trying to show that the profinite completion $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$ (as topological groups) where $p$ runs through all prime numbers and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denotes the ring of $p$-adic integers.

By definition, we know that $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the inverse limit of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the inverse limit of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$. Furthermore, the Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us that if $n = \prod_p p^{e_p(n)}$ denotes the prime factorization of $n$, then we have $$ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \simeq \prod_p \mathbb{Z}/p^{e_p(n)} \mathbb{Z}.$$

So I would like to show that
$$
\hat{\mathbb{Z}} = \varprojlim_n \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \simeq \varprojlim_n \prod_p \mathbb{Z}/p^{e_p(n)} \mathbb{Z} = \prod_p \varprojlim_n \mathbb{Z}/p^{e_p(n)} \mathbb{Z} = \prod_p \varprojlim_n \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z} = \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p,
$$

but I am not sure about these steps, especially with the third and fourth step. Could you please give me an easy explanation whether this works or not? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can. A product is a particular case of an inverse limit and you can interchange inverse limits.

Comment: More generally you can interchange any two limits (in the categorical sense; in particular "direct limits" are *not* limits)

Comment: Okay, that is good to know! Could you maybe explain the second last step as well? I do not really see why this is true.

Comment: As far as your original question is concerned, giving an element $ x \in \widehat{\mathbb{Z}} $ is the same as giving a sequence of residues $ x_n \in \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z} $ which are compatible wrt the projection maps, and by the CRT, it is enough to specify the residues $ x_{p^e} , e \ge 1 $ and $ p $ prime, to recover $ x $. Now for each prime, the sequence $ x_{p^e} , e \ge 1 $ is itself compatible wrt the projection maps, so is an element of $ \mathbb{Z}_p $. In this way you get the isomorphism without really bothering about whether products commute with inverse limits.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi why are we allowed to take the second-last step?, i.e. changing the $e_p(n)$ into $n$? It seems to me that $\prod_n \mathbf{Z}/p^{e_p(n)}\mathbf{Z}$ gives a lot of "double" factors..

Comment: @MaximeRamzi, also this establishes a set-theoretical bijection. Is it easy to see that this is also an isomorphism of _topological_ rings?

Comment: @rae306 : for the first question, no there are double factors : you're ordering $\mathbb N$ along divisibility, so if $n\mid m$, $e_p(n) \leq e_p(m)$ and so the map $\mathbb Z/p^{e_p(m)} \to\mathbb Z/p^{e_p(n)}$ is just the canonical projection. If the two are equal, in the inverse limit, it doesn't play a role.

Comment: @rae306  For the second question, you can take these limits as limits of topological rings (where each $\mathbb Z/n, \mathbb Z/p^{e_p(n)}$ is taken with the discrete topology. Limits of topological rings are computed as in sets, so that's not an issue